# Java streams filter OR condition

Tags: java, stream

I have this list of string values. My condition is to filter out NON numeric values that are not of length 6.
I got the 2 filters below,how do i add in my or condition?

Thanks

```
List<String> teList = new ArrayList<String>();
teList.add("123456");
teList.add("76543W");
teList.add("123R56");
teList.add("888888");
teList.add("7652");
teList.add("222222222222");
teList.add("1234526R");
teList.add("76543222R");

List<String> exlist = teList.stream()
    .filter(s -> !s.matches("[0-9]+"))
    .filter(s -> s.length() != 6)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(exlist.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert your conditions and join them with an or (`||`). (You want to keep values that are numeric or have a length of 6. See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).)

```java
List<String> exlist = teList.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.length() == 6 || s.matches("[0-9]+"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: For what it's worth, in this case you should flip your conditions; the length is nearly instantaneous to test, but the pattern match is very expensive (especially without a precompiled pattern).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- what would be your proposed solution? do post it. thanks for sharing